# Android. Add controls programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-inflate

I have layout with controls:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/contact_phones_layout_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/contact_phone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/contact_phone_type"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And I want to inflate it into another layout on the fragment. Quantity of these controls depends on values in a array. Array contains controls objects. So every time onCreateView rises I filled the layout from the array:

```
private void addLine(PhoneLine line) {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.contact_phones_layout);
        View view = line.getParent();
        ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
        layout.addView(view, layout.getChildCount() - 1);
        setButtonVisible(false);
    }
```

if line is null controls are created this way:

```
private void addLine() {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.contact_phones_layout);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_phone_line, layout, false);
        EditText phoneEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone);
        Spinner phoneType = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone_type);
        phoneLines.add(new PhoneLine(phoneEditText, phoneType, view));
        layout.addView(view, layout.getChildCount() - 1);
    }
```

But after that I get same values in all EditText/Spinner controls, values equal to last element in the array. What can be wrong? May be there is more pure way to add controls dynamically?

Comment: Try `ListView` maybe?

Comment: All controls on the layout are inside ScrollView, so I cant use ListView

Comment: Replace your LinearLayout with ListView. And keep it inside ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding controls when onResume rises, not onCreateView. But I still don't understand why onCreateView changes all values.